# Textarea width/height work like minimal size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a textarea that can be resized by user. So I want this textarea to have a setted in css width&height as initial and maximum size. But width&height work like minimum size.

For example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8t2E8/

```
width: 600px;
height: 200px;
```

Initial size is 600*200. I can make textarea only bigger, but need only smaller.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/8t2E8/1/)

```
textarea{
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    max-width: 600px;
    max-height:200px;
    min-width: 300px;
    min-height: 50px;
}
```

Although, you should check this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16214981/2668547) :(**

Comment: Try setting the `width` and `height` so that they are greater than the `min-width` and `min-height`, you will see that `min-width` and `min-height` have no effect at all (tested in Chrome, Opera and Maxthon), only FF treats it differently.

Comment: Well, it should have initial size same as maximum)

Answer (score 0):

```
textarea{
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    min-width: 300px;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: have you tested this yet? I had tested this before you posted this answer and it did not work.

Comment: yes, looks like it works only in FF, does not work in Chrome, Opera and Maxthon (regardless of IE because IE does not support resizable textarea).

Answer (score 0):

```
textarea{
max-width: 600px;
max-height: 200px;
}
```