# How can I use CSS `resize` to resize an element to a height/width less than initial height/width on Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, resize

I have just seen that on Chromium

- I can't resize an element to a height smaller than its initial height in case of `resize:vertical` or `resize:both`
- I can't resize an element to a width smaller than its initial width in case of `resize:horizontal` or `resize:both`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3rdj4/3

I have read [w3c spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui/#resize), and I guess the problem comes because of this:

> The user agent **may** restrict the resizing range to something suitable,
>   such as between the **original formatted size** of the element, and large
>   enough to encompass all the element's contents.

Is there a way to do it, even if Chrome applies the paragraph above?

**Note**: I use Chromium 30.0.1592.0 (216775)

Comment: +1 for the Q *<worried>* I cannot believe actually I'm reading this question... When, when on earth will finally browsers shake-hands? I need another coffee. *</worried>*

Comment: There's a solution in this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146449

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm gonna say no(t without javascript).

[Custom CSS to allow chrome textarea resize smaller than initial state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146449/custom-css-to-allow-chrome-textarea-resize-smaller-than-initial-state)

> The fact you cannot resize a textarea under its initial dimensions is
>   reported as a bug
>   (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=94583)

Answer (score 4):

A Javascript solution:

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/nz8ut/2/

```
function resizableStart(e){
    this.originalW = this.clientWidth;
    this.originalH = this.clientHeight;
    this.onmousemove = resizableCheck;
    this.onmouseup = this.onmouseout = resizableEnd;
}
function resizableCheck(e){
    if(this.clientWidth !== this.originalW || this.clientHeight !== this.originalH) {
        this.originalX = e.clientX;
        this.originalY = e.clientY;
        this.onmousemove = resizableMove;
    }
}
function resizableMove(e){
    var newW = this.originalW + e.clientX - this.originalX,
        newH = this.originalH + e.clientY - this.originalY;
    if(newW < this.originalW){
        this.style.width = newW + 'px';
    }
    if(newH < this.originalH){
        this.style.height = newH + 'px';
    }
}
function resizableEnd(){
    this.onmousemove = this.onmouseout = this.onmouseup = null;
}

var els = document.getElementsByClassName('resizable');
for(var i=0, len=els.length; i<len; ++i){
    els[i].onmouseover = resizableStart;
}
```

---

The solution above uses `mouseover` and `mouseout` to trigger `resizableStart` and `resizableEnd`. The problem is that if the element being resized has childs, when the mouse is placed over a child, the element receives a `mouseout` event and, just after that, it receives a `mouserover` event which bubbles from child.

To avoid those events I have implemented another solution with `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events:

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/nz8ut/3/

Answer (score 0):

A very simply solution here (can be rewritten in pure javascript):

```
$("element").mousedown(function() {
    $("element").css({height:'50px', width: '50px'});
});
```

When you first click, the original size of element will be changed to smaller one, but since you still hold the button - it will restore its size immidiately, and then you can easy change the size however you want.

The '50px', or height with width isn't fixed of course, adjust it after your needs.

Comment: Tried it and it squashes the area to 50px high if the page is scrollable and a click anywhere in the textarea causes that to happen. So not a solution that works for me.

Comment: You can add a count that only first click will make it 50x50, after that this function will stop to work t.ex. and you can click and type. Not the prettiest solution, but something short.

Answer (score -3):

How about adding a min-height/max-height?

This allows it to be set beyond the initial.

http://jsfiddle.net/Dqxua/

```
#wrapper {
    min-height:200px;
    max-height: 400px;
    resize: vertical;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```